# Button sound on all touch down events

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

Is there an easy way to add a sound to a button on *every* touch down event?

Because I have a lot of buttons in my project, and maybe there is a way to do this.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a subclass of UIButton that overwrites the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method and have it play a sound.  Just be sure to also call `[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];` and `[self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];` (I forget if both are necessary) to ensure the touch gets passed on

Comment: would this work across every view? like if I did it in the AppDelegate... or will I have to do it separately on each view

Comment: Like I said, make it a UIButton subclass and make all your buttons the subclass, this will only effect the buttons and not the whole view.

Comment: okay, sounds good. And this method is acceptable on the AppStore (i.e. it won't get rejected)?

Comment: It's not using any private APIs or anything that violates the guidelines so it will not be rejected

Answer (score 0):

Create a subclass of `UIButton` that incorporates the sound, something like `SoundButton`.  Then replace all of your `UIButton` objects with `SoundButton`s.  (This can be done with find and replace if you made them programmatically, or you can go through and assign them to your subclass using the inspector if you made them in interface builder.)

Comment: would this work across every view? like if I did it in the AppDelegate... or will I have to do it separately on each view

Comment: If you change each of your `UIButton`s to `SoundButton`s and `SoundButton`s are set up to make a sound, then yes, it will work everywhere that you make a `SoundButton`.